# What is the Record type and How and when to use it in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

How and when to use the `Record` type in dart and What is the difference between using it and other collection types like map, list, etc?

Also, In [Dart doc](https://dart.dev/language/records) it states that records are real values, what does that mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A record is not a "collection type". I think that is very misleading.

It is basically a very short and dynamic way to declare a class that holds fields and nothing else.

For example `({int r, int g, int b}) color` this is a variable of a type that has three fields of type int, named `r`, `g` and `b`.

You could have made a class:

```
class Color {
   final int r;
   final int g;
   final int b;

   Color({this.r, this.b, this.g});
}
```

That would serve the same purpose, it's just a lot more work and a lot more class definitions. Because:

> Records automatically define `hashCode` and `==` methods based on the structure of their fields.

So it is a very practical and time saving way to use field-aggregates. Or "data holder classes". It is not a replacement for collections. Collections are a varying number of elements of the same type, records are a predefined number of varying types.

Answer (score -3):

```
       /// this called record type 
    /// first you put your record's data types in brackets
    ///  the order is important
     /// [myRecord]  is the name of your record variable
     /// (1,'kururu' , 28)   remember the order  (num ID , Object name , num age)
    (num , Object , num)  myRecord = (1  ,"Kururu" ,28);
    
    void main(List<String> args) {

      //using record to initialize multi variables in one line
       //remember the order of your record  (INT ,STRING ,INT)
        // number ,name , age    are your variable 
// assign them to your record 
// and that's it:)
      var (number as int, name as String , age as int  ) = myRecord;
      print(number);
      print(name) ;
      print(age) ;
    
    }
```

something like this?